# my Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8.1

why when in want to write 2 word in textbox1 just get the first word?

example:
when I write "France and England" in textbox1...
in textbox to show me "Paris" just!
I want to show me the 2 word in same time??

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("France", "Paris");
        dictionary.Add("England", "London");
        dictionary.Add("Jordan", "Amman");


        if (textbox1.Text == "France")
        {
            string value = dictionary["France"];
            textbox2.Text = value;
        }

        else if (textbox1.Text == "England")
        {
            string value = dictionary["England"];
            textbox2.Text = value;
        }}
```

Comment: I miss a closing `}`, as well ass capital letters at the start of each sentence and complete correct English sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are entering two values in textbox1 and you want to display them both in textbox2.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("France", "Paris");
    dictionary.Add("England", "London");
    dictionary.Add("Jordan", "Amman");

    textbox2.Text = "";
    if (textbox1.Text.Contains("France"))
    {
        string value = dictionary["France"];
        textbox2.Text += value;
    }

    if (textbox1.Text.Contains("England"))
    {
        string value = dictionary["England"];
        textbox2.Text += value;
    }

    if (textbox1.Text.Contains("Jordan"))
    {
        string value = dictionary["Jordan"];
        textbox2.Text += value;
    }
}
```

You can add separators such as commas and 'and's between the concatenations.

Answer (score 1):

You reset the value of the textbox2 all the time.

You need to add the new text to the textbox2 like so.

Like this:
`textbox2.Text += value;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is complete (which is hard to tell, as there's no closing `}` - did you forget to paste some?), your conditions are checking if `textbox1`'s `Text` value is "England" or "France" (but not both).

If you want the  value "England and France", you need to specifically check for it (`if (textbox1.Text == "England and France" || textbox1.text = "France and England") ...`).  In fact, if you want that you'd probably be best off calling `string.Split()` on the text of `textbox1` and evaluating each of the words in it to see if they're in the `Dictionary` or not - if so, append the dictionary value to a `StringBuilder` and put **that** in your `textbox2`.

If on the other hand, you want to just append values into `textbox2` (user presses button after entering "England", and then presses it again after entering "France"), just change your code to update `textbox2` to something like

```
if (textbox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    textbox2.Text = textbox2.Text + " and " + value;
}
else
{
    textbox2.Text = value;
}
```